# error in OpenCV svm->predict()

Tags: opencv, c++14

I use predict() in my program, the flowing is my codes:

```
int plateJudge(vector<Mat>& inVec,vector<Mat>& resultVec){

size_t num = inVec.size();
for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
{
    Mat inMat = inVec[j];
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(inMat,gray,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(gray,gray);
    Mat p = gray.reshape(1, 1);
    p.convertTo(p, CV_32FC1);
    int response = (int)svm->predict(p);
    if (response == 1)
    {
        resultVec.push_back(inMat);
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

but I got the error:

```
error: (-215) samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == 5 in function predict
```

I have translate the image to gray format & change the array as 1*n, it still didn't work. Besides,the `svm` has already been defined well(using the trained model).So, that's all. Wish for answers! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass same dimension matrix that you may had passed during training.

Comment: @Nilambar
"
    Mat input = Mat( 1, arraysize(data), CV_32FC1, data);
    auto score = svm->predict(input,output, cv::ml::StatModel::RAW_OUTPUT);
"
Here the data is [1,128] dimentional array that is the same shape which is used during training.